PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 24): 'Twas the Meta before Christmas
This puzzle is part of the Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2024. The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 250 reputation.< Previous Door 
Just caught up with my friend Declan and learned that there was much more to the 'puzzling version' Advent calendar I'd previously accidentally ordered for him. It turns out that in addition to the words behind each door, there was also an extra image printed on the reverse side of each door that I'd not noticed before.
Declan has torn off the 24 cardboard doors and posted them through my letterbox with a challenge - he asks me: Can you reassemble the original calendar, and uncover the secret festive message held within it? I've reproduced both sides of the doors below, arbitrarily 'numbering' them with Greek letters (24 of them after all - it seemed perfect!) in the random order I picked them out of the envelope. Hopefully, you can make sense of it all in time for Christmas!
α (alpha):

β (beta):

Image text:
?V?L F? ?AV
L Y?T??V?C
??IL T??S
γ (gamma):

Image text:
A: 1 'Despicable' Minions chief 5 European capital 7 ? 8 Clips 9 Greek letter;
D: 2 Hitchcock film 3 Employment 4 Male child 6 Inventory 7 Secret agent.
δ (delta):

ε (epsilon):

ζ (zeta):

η (eta):

θ (theta):

Image text as .csv:
 , , , ,X,A,V,W, , , , , , , , ,
 , , , ,T,B,B,K, , , , , , , , ,
 , , , ,I,I,V, , , , , , , , , ,
 , , , ,V,K,S,A, , , , , , , , ,
T, ,J,U,U,R,W,N,F,C,A,B,P,H,P,E,
J,N,O,S, ,X,O, ,Y,G,Y,N,R, ,U,H,
Y, , ,P,M,D,C,H,F,N,H,Y,I, ,V,W,
U,Z,T,I, ,O,X,N,Y, ,N,M, ,V,S,H,
 , , , ,J,B,V,Z, , , , , , , , ,
 , , , , ,M, ,W, , , , , , , , ,
 , , , ,V, ,M,X, , , , , , , , ,
 , , , ,W,Q,C,M, , , , , , , , ,

Hint:

 The lengths of the Caesar shifts used to encrypt (not decrypt) these six texts follow a useful pattern of their own...

ι (iota):

Image text: Across Negative, Verify; Down Fashionable, Party; Wraps Laceration, Naïve, Sacred, Skated.
κ (kappa):

Image text as a table:




?? Chamber ??





Pheasant
Through
Course


Spleen
Ben
Bean


Toulouse
Den
Behemoth


Philip
Head
Approach


Nor
Vision
Hello



λ (lambda):

μ (mu):

Image text: Jared wants to play too!
ν (nu):

Image text:
A: 1 Welcome 7 Achy 8 Vehicle 10 Biscuit 11 Polonius' daughter 13 Do 16 Novel 17 Endor local 18 Discern (2 wds)
D: 2 Shear 3 Lingerie 4 Umpire 5 Cain's bro 6 Mutt 7 Ladle 9 Taste 12 Peddle 13 Pulse 14 Duo 15 Thee
ξ (xi):

Image text: Best bits of Flitwick's subject? Children with weapons, and it's within Hogwarts' walls!
ο (omicron):

π (pi):

Image text, clockwise from top: INIGO, COAL, SCUM, SCHOOL, TREASON, WATER, BLOOD, INK.
ρ (rho):

σ (sigma):

τ (tau):

Hint:

 Only some of the emojis are directly needed for the extraction - exactly one third of them, in fact. These emojis together make up a complete set. The first letters of the remaining emojis spell a useful instruction (use MS Teams shortcut keywords).

υ (upsilon):

Image text: 1s2 2s2 2p6 3s2 3p4
φ (phi):

Image text as a table:











Bonfire
Carpet
Diggity
Disaster


Gladys
Ireland
Isaac
Jedi


Jersey
Juice
Lights
Logarithm


Mexico
Rain
Selection
Scrubs


Territory
Thandiwe
Thanksgiving
Veterans


York






χ (chi):

Image text as a table:



Pieces





R.C.E?IN.
******** ****


S.I.FL.N?
******


O.NO?.OU.
******


LI..O?IC.
*****


.A..ARO?S
****


?ROGS.A..
****


.?ADBL.C.
****



ψ (psi):

ω (omega):

Image text: Twelfth helmet too noble ? (1 6 4 2 9)

Would it be possible to have each of the smaller images be separate, or would that mess with the formatting too much?

@Mikez Unfortunately since it's now Christmastime proper I won't have time to do this any time soon (minor text edits only really), but will try to do so later in the holidays (although that may come too late for solvers, I realise). Merry Christmas everyone!

We are not worthy.

As a metapuzzle, this

 makes reference to all the previous days of the PSE Advent Calendar.

α:

 Just like on day 6, we need to translate the color of the gifts into the given country's language, and then index by how many there are.

 Green in French is "vert", and there are 4, so we take the letter T.

β:

 On day 7, we had many reversed 'gifts' with the sound "cara" removed, and some letters masked away by question marks.

 Here, the gifts are:
[cara]vaN Of lOvE
cOvENtRy [caro]l
sWEEt [caro]LIna
 The boxed letter is a W.

γ?:

 This is a blocked crossword, a la day 17's.


 The unclued entry is SPAIN. This should somehow extract an E, though it's not clear to me exactly how...

δ:

 Day 12 had us identifying various video games and solving minipuzzles with them. Here, we instead have four board games: Lost Cities, Axis & Allies, Snakes & Ladders, and Tiddlywinks. The first letters of each of these spell out LAST; the last letter of all of them is S.

ε:

 Day 5 had us decoding a christmas tree as a Morse tree. The marked ornament is the letter S.

ζ:

 On day 20, we decoded holly leaves as flag semaphore. Doing this here gives FIRST LETTER, which is A.

η:

 In day 3, parts of crossword clues were replaced by notes. This clue is "MI5 director"; this may refer to Maxwell Knight, who signed his notes "M" (and inspired the character "M" in the James Bond series).

θ:

 On day 10, we had to use Caesar shifts on messages on various sides of a cube.

 Doing that here gives, for three of the sides, "PLANCK'S CONSTANT", "LIGHTEST ELEMENT", and "LINE OF DUTY FOE". All three of these have the same answer: H.


 (Not sure about the other three sides.)

ι:

 On day 21, tiny crosswords were solved and then "wrapped" with more entries.

 The same process works here...

 ...highlighting the letter S.

κ:

 Like Day 4, this is a puzzle in the style of GHCQ's "word association". The words given can be divided into equal-sized groups, where each member of a group is associated with another word in the same way. The words are sorted alphabetically by their associated words. One entry is left out, and the solver must figure out where it goes.

 The four groups here are:
 - ends in a bug (Pheasant→ANT, Toulouse→LOUSE, Behemoth→MOTH, Approach→ROACH)
 - rhymes with a color (Through→BLUE, Spleen→GREEN, Head→RED, Hello→YELLOW)
 - First half of a country (Ben→IN, Den→MARK, Philip→PINES, Nor→WAY)
 - Forms phrase when prepended by NATO alphabet letter (Course→GOLF, Bean→LIMA, Vision→X-RAY)

 "Chamber" fits in the last group, leading to the word ECHO and the letter E.

λ:

 This is a reference to day 1. The snowflakes are braille for the letter W.

μ:

 In day 2, the reindeer were assigned chemical elements based on their names. Using the same rule on Jared would give Ar, for Argon. (Unlike the other puzzles, this gives two letters, not one.)

ν:

 This is a crossword with the solution:

 On day 13, there were many synonyms for "kiss" clued in other ways.

 The entire outer ring of the grid has forms of affection: EMBRACE, SMACK, SPOON, MAKE OUT. This draws out the letter O.

ξ:

 On day 16, we solved cryptic clues leading to nonsense phrases that were anagrams of CHRISTMAS plus one letter.

 This clue solves to CHARMS HITS (CH + ARMS + IT within H...S), and has an extra H.

ο:

 In day 9, XORing gifts together produced a new image. Here, the two gifts XOR to produce the letter S.

π:

 On day 15 we had to figure out what went at the center of a Venn diagram.

 The categories here are:
 - Top: One letter off of a color (IN[D]IGO, CO[R]AL, [P]INK)
 - Left: Liquids
 - Bottom: Can make a phrase when preceded by "high"
 - Right: [???]
 The word in the middle is therefore TEA, which gives us the letter T.

ρ:

 Like day 11, this is a Between Thermo Sudoku.
 (To solve: The cell in the middle of the Between line must be between two others, so it must be U or L; L is already in that row, so it must be U, and Y must go in the bottom right. The rest is easy.)



 The letter in the question-marked spot is E.

σ:

 Like day 22, this puzzle involves pigpen - except this time it's the actual Pigpen cipher. The given letters decode to B C N ? F on top, and P S below. This is part of the periodic table; the missing letter is O.

τ?:

 (still unsure how to solve this one, but it must give an E)

υ:

 In day 18, we looked at electron configurations for various elements. This is the electron configuration for sulfur, or S.

φ?:

 Like [day 23]'s puzzle, the 21 words here can be divided into groups, where the words within a group are all associated with the same word.

 I've found some of the groups, but not all...


 ...but it's clear that the letter we need here is N.

χ:

 Day 14 had us solving a chess puzzle with gravity. There was a certain encoding scheme for the pieces, where each was assigned a three-letter code.

 We can fill those codes in to the dots, and then each row spells a word:

 Reading columnwise, we get FOXTROT, giving us the letter F.

ψ:

 We'll come back to this one.

ω:

 On day 8 we anagrammed phrases into Lutheran hymns. This one anagrams to "O Little Town of Bethlehem", number 361 in the Lutheran Service Book... except an I is missing.


Now what?

 If you look back through the puzzles, you might realize...

 The 'doors' are actually ripped out from this image we saw on day 4!



 If we put each letter in its proper slot, we get words spelled out across the rows.



 Hey, these are all the things that ψ has images of - this confirms the letters we have, and also confirms that ψ is indeed today's puzzle!

That's the original calendar. What about the festive message?

 If we instead order the extracted letters by day rather than by position, we get our final message: WArMEST WISHES OF THE SEASON!


For $\gamma$, Spain leading to E might be the cryptic crossword way of referring to the country as España

Missing category for π rot13(*ont); φ rot13(obasver gunaxftvivat irgrenaf -> abirzore) rot13(qvttvgl enva fpehof -> ab)

Addendum to θ: rot13(EBG25(yrsg snpr) vf FVKGL ZVA FUBEG, naq EBG23(sne evtug snpr) vf ZRZORE BS FGRCF. EBG18(obggbz snpr) vf gur zbfg cebzvfvat yrnq, ohg V pna'g znxr frafr bs vg.)

Partial solution, need help with formatting though.

 Each big picture references one of the previous 2024 Advent puzzles, and each small picture can fit into Day 4's calendar image. They can be assigned as follows:
 - A Snowy Christmas (Day 1): Lambda (The snowflakes)
 - Roleplaying Reindeer (Day 2): Mu (The only reindeer one)
 - A Cacophonic Crossword (Day 3): Eta (The musical notes)
 - "Where Should Declan Go?" (Day 4): Kappa? (Not sure on this one)
 - 835 (Day 5): Epsilon (The tree with lines)
 - Colorful Gifts (Day 6): Alpha (Colored gifts from a country)
 - Santa's In A Pickle! (Day 7): Beta (Missing letters and question marks)
 - Look, Santa’s Baffled (Day 8): Omega (The anagram section)
 - Special Wrapping Paper (Day 9): Omicron (Two similar gifts with slight differences)
 - Locked Christmas Present (Day 10): Theta (A diagram of a cube with letters on it)
 - A Sparkling Sudoku (Day 11): Rho (The only sudoku one)
 - 12 Days Of Gaming (Day 12): Delta? (The original puzzle was based on games?)
 - ‘Tis The Season For... Diamonds? (Day 13): Nu (The crossword has bars instead of black squares)
 - Chess With Gravity #3 (Day 14): Chi (The pieces list)
 - 2122 (Day 15): Pi (The venn diagram)
 - Holly Jolly Cryptic Word Tapestry (Day 16): Xi (The cryptic clue has no length indicator)
 - The Sun Will Come Out Tomorrow (Day 17): Gamma (The crossword has black squares instead of bars)
 - A Sweet & Short Expected Chemistry Christmas Puzzle (Day 18): Upsilon (The electron notation)
 - A Christmas Puzzle In (1)225 Characters (Day 19): Tau? (Not sure on this one)
 - Holly (Day 20): Zeta (The holly leaves in semaphore)
 - Wrap-Up (Day 21): Iota (The wraps column and the green square)
 - Away In A Manger (Day 22): Sigma? (The only one with pigpen references?)
 - 2089 (Day 23): Phi? (The table format matches?)
 - and 'Twas the Meta before Christmas (Day 24): Psi? (The only one left, not sure on this one)

